# Using bit operations to fill an int set

Tags: c++, set, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Let's say we have a function in a form of `void Fill(char *in, int *out)` in C++ that is supposed to read binary sequences of 5 characters from `char *in`, convert them to int = i and switch `int *out`'s ith place from `0` to `1`.

Example: `char *in` is:

`'   00101  10010    '`, so the values are 5 and 18.

`int *out` is primarily empty and has got 32 empty bits, so it is:
`0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`.

Since our read numbers are 5 and 18, we have to turn (counting from 0) 5th `0` into `1` and 18th `0` into `1` in our `int *out`.

Final `int *out` would look like this: `0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0010 0000`. In other words, our `int *out` is a specific type of set, that "lights" `1s` if a number from `char *in` is present in it.

I want to code this, and I have figured out that the best way to do this would be to use bit operations.
I know that I have to iterate through the `char *in` itself using recursion, but i'm having trouble in finding a way of inserting these `char *in` values (lighting `1s`) into our `int *out`.

My code for iterating through `char *in` recursively is below:

```cpp
if(*(in) != '\0' ){

        if(*(in) != ' '){
            cout << *in;
            Emplace(in + 1, out);
        }
        else{
            Emplace(in + 1, out);
        }
    }
```

It goes through the whole thing until the end and passes every space since we only need binary characters.

My question is - how do I do the `1` lighting now? How do I read a value from this char and somehow "turn on" the `1` in the `int *out` at the right place?

Thank you kindly and sorry for such a long post.

Comment: You can use strtok which can split using spaces. Once you have the string consisting of 5 bits, convert that to the integer `i`. Then do `out|=1<<(i);` Also, do you mean `int *out` or `int out`

Comment: @risingStark I mean `int *out`. I cannot use strings and loops, that's the thing. I somehow have to convert this char array into int and then switch the `1s` in the `*out`

Comment: Does `out` have to be a pointer or normal int.

Comment: No loops? Then how will anyone iterate through the `char *in`?

Comment: it has to be a pointer. And you have to use recursion in order to iterate over the char I believe

Comment: Trying to solve this problem using recursion but no loops is like trying to eat soup with chopsticks when there is a spoon on the table.

Comment: Okay, I will try using that

Comment: @f33tl0v3r Can't you use a `std::bitset<32> blah;` for this? And then do a `*out = static_cast<int>(blah.to_ulong());`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with an idea!

```cpp
void Fill(char *in, int *out, int i){

    if(*(in+i) != '\0'){

        if(*(in + i) != ' '){

            int temp_int = 1;

            if(*(in + i) == '1')
                temp_int <<= 16;
            i++;

            if(*(in + i) == '1')
                temp_int <<= 8;
            i++;

            if(*(in + i) == '1')
                temp_int <<= 4;
            i++;

            if(*(in + i) == '1')
                temp_int <<= 2;
            i++;

            if(*(in + i) == '1')
                temp_int <<= 1;

            Union(temp_int, *out, out);
        }
        i++;
        Fill(in, out, i);
    }
}
```

Basically we create a temporary integer, we shift its "1" to the left according to the char values and then we make a Union with the original `*out`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the in-built C function [`char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters );`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) to split the string between spaces. Then convert the obtained binary string to decimal. Then use bitwse `|`(or) operator to combine the result of the current obtained integer `i` with previously set `*out` value.

[bitset in c++ stl](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/) to see the variables in binary

```
void recur(char *in, int *out, char *tok){
    if(tok == NULL){
        return;
    }
    int i = 16*(tok[0]-'0') + 8*(tok[1]-'0') + 4*(tok[2]-'0') + 2*(tok[3]-'0') + 1*(tok[4]-'0');
    *out |= 1<<i;
    /*
    // Uncomment this block to see the value of variables as well
    cout<<"Current Sequence of 5 bits = "<<tok<<endl;
    cout<<"Sequence of 5 bits converted to integer i = "<<i<<endl;
    bitset<32> b(*out); 
    cout<<"Current Value of *out = "<<b<<endl<<endl;
    */
    recur(in, out, strtok(NULL, " "));
}

void Fill(char *in, int *out){
    char *tok = strtok(in, " ");
    recur(in, out, tok);
}
```